# Dynamic String Reaplcement Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to write a jQuery function to replace all instances of "`CASA/Builder`" with `CASA` dynamically in my form...after running the project. I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body, body *').contents().filter(function() {
         return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && this.nodeValue.indexOf('CASA/Builder') >= 0;
     }).each(function() {
            this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(/\bCASA/Builder\b/gi,'CASA');
    });
});
```

but it doesn't take "/"...so string is not getting replaced.
I'm using this for now:

```
var str = document.getElementById("custBuilderAcct").innerHTML; 
var res = str.replace("CASA/Builder", "CASA");
document.getElementById("custBuilderAcct").innerHTML = res;
```

but I want jQuery code for this, if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the "/".

Instead of `/\bCASA/Builder\b/gi`, you would write `/\bCASA\/Builder\b/gi`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var res = $('#custBuilderAcct').html().replace(/\CASA\/Builder/g, 'CASA');
$('#custBuilderAcct').html(res);
```

Check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uhy712dv/).